# Tailwind CSS: Two Rows with Four Equal-Size Divs (First Row with Margin Issue)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to achieve something like this:

[image: I want to achieve something like this]

I'm trying to create a layout in React using Tailwind CSS with two rows, each containing four equally sized div elements, while having margins only on the first row divs.

I wrote the below code but it's not responsive and seems a little bad, I think there must be a better way:)

```
<div className="w-full max-w-5xl relative my-10">
        <div className="pt-9">
          <div className="w-full grid grid-cols-4 text-center text-primaryPurple gap-x-10 absolute top-0 capitalize font-bold text-xl overflow-hidden">
            <span className="bg-[#FF9900] rounded-t-xl py-1">rank</span>
            <span className="bg-[#FF9900] rounded-t-xl py-1">account</span>
            <span className="bg-[#FF9900] rounded-t-xl py-1">date</span>
            <span className="bg-[#FF9900] rounded-t-xl py-1">likes</span>
          </div>
          <div className="grid grid-cols-4 text-center text-white font-bold text-2xl gap-x-10 bg-primaryPurple capitalize py-5 rounded-b-xl">
            <span>213th</span>
            <span>2024/12/2</span>
            <span>5</span>
            <span>84</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: "but it's not responsive" In what way would you like it responsive? "seems a little bad" what would make it better for you?

Answer (score 0):

The design can be tricky specially if you want it to be responsive but can be achieve by using pseudo elements and classes such as `:before`, `:after`, `:not`, `:first`, `:last`. Also doable in pure tailwind css by the help of `group-*` modifiers.

I provided a snippet below to see it in action. View in full page so you can play around and resize screen.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  
<body class="bg-blue-600">
  <div id="root" class="p-4 pb-32"></div>

  <script type="text/babel">
    const data = [
      { label: 'Rank', value: '213th' },
      { label: 'Account', value: '2024/12/2' },
      { label: 'Date', value: '5' },
      { label: 'Likes', value: '84' }
    ];

    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="grid grid-cols-6 gap-10 sm:grid-cols-12">
          {data.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={index} className="grid col-span-3 group">
              <p className="bg-amber-500 rounded-t-lg font-medium text-center p-1">
                {item.label}
              </p>
              <p className="relative bg-slate-950 rounded-b-lg text-white font-medium text-lg text-center p-2.5 before:bg-slate-950 group-first:before:hidden group-last:after:hidden group-even:after:hidden group-odd:before:hidden before:absolute before:-left-5 before:top-0 before:w-full before:h-full before:z-[-1] before:content-[' '] after:bg-slate-950 after:absolute after:-right-5 after:top-0 after:w-full after:h-full after:z-[-1] after:content-[' '] sm:group-[:nth-child(odd):not(:first-child)]:before:block sm:group-[:nth-child(even):not(:last-child)]:after:block">
                {item.value}
              </p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
  </script>
</body>
```

***Disclaimer**:
While I provided a solution to your current problem, I encourage you to explore different approaches when you have extra time. This challenge can help you develop a deeper understanding of the problem and improve your problem-solving skills.*